# the digits after decimal point of are replaced with 0 in bison and flex

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc

I am new in bison and flex.I assign floating value suppose a=12.34 .But when I print the value I find 12.000000.Please help me .Thanks in advance.The lex file ruturn float value very well.I print the value in different place of code and that is ok.But when the value assigned in a variable then the problem arise and then replace the values after decimal point by ).

Here is my bison file

```
    /*C declarations (types, variables, functions, preprocessor commands)*/

    %{
        #include<stdio.h>
        # include <stdlib.h>
        # include <stdarg.h>
        # include <string.h>
        # include <math.h>
        
        int yylex(void);
        int check[100],int_val[1000],var_type[1000];
        float float_val[1000];
        char char_val[1000];
        int caseD,caseV;
        
        
        
        
    %}
    /* Bison declarations (grammar symbols, operator precedence decl., attribute data type) */
    %error-verbose

       %union{
      int intVal;
      char* variable;
      char* strVal;
      float floatVal;
      char charVal;
    }
     
     
     %token Begin INTEGER FLOAT CHAR END COLON SEMICOLON ASSIGN COMMA  FORWARD_ARROW SHOW 
     %token BACKWARD_ARROW TAKE PLUS SUB MULT DIV MOD OTB CTB POW SIN COS TAN LOG LOG10 OP CP 
     %token LESS_THAN GREATER_THAN LESS_EQUAL GREATER_EQUAL IF ELSE_IF ELSE EQUAL NOT_EQUAL INC
     %token DEC FOR IN FOR_INC FOR_DEC EVEN_ODD FACTORIAL SUM GCD LCM SWITCH
     %token DEFAULT WHILE OSB CSB
     
     %token<intVal>INT_VAL
     %token<floatVal>FLOAT_VAL
     %token<charVal>CHAR_VAL
     %token<intVal>VARIABLE
     %token<strVal>STRING_VAL

     
     %type<intVal>expression statements cdeclare condition cstatements number
   

    %%

    program:Begin COLON cstatements END   {printf("\n\t\t\t\t\tCompilation Done Succesfully!!!\n");
                                                
                                          
                                          }
           ;
    cstatements:/* Empty */           {}
               |SEMICOLON                       {printf("\n\t\t\t\tEmpty statement\n");}
               |cstatements cdeclare SEMICOLON  
               |cstatements statements
               
               
              
               ;
    cdeclare:FLOAT float_id {}
            
                
            ;
   
    float_id:float_id1 COMMA float_id 
      |float_id1
      ;
    float_id1:VARIABLE      {
                                if(check[$1]==1)
                                 {
                                   printf("\n\t\t\t\tCompilation error-> %c is redeclared \n",$1+97);
                                 }
                                else{
                                var_type[$1]=1;
                                check[$1]=1;
                                printf("\n\t\t\t\t%c is declared successfully\n",$1+97);
                               }
                            }
        |VARIABLE ASSIGN expression {   
                                        if(check[$1]==1)
                                         {
                                           printf("\n\t\t\t\tCompilation error-> %c is redeclared \n",$1+97);
                                         }
                                        else{
                                        var_type[$1]=1;
                                        check[$1]=1;
                                        float_val[$1]=$3;
                                        printf("\n\t\t\t\t%c is declared and assigned by %f successfully\n",$1+97,(float)($3));
                                       }
                                
                               }
        
        ;
        
   
                               
        
        

    statements:SHOW FORWARD_ARROW VARIABLE SEMICOLON       { 
                                                                if(check[$3] == 1) 
                                                                    {
                                                                     if(var_type[$3]==0)
                                                                        printf("\n\t\t\t\tValue of %c is: %d\n",$3+97,int_val[$3]);
                                                                     else if(var_type[$3]==1)
                                                                        printf("\n\t\t\t\tValue of %c is: %f\n",$3+97,float_val[$3]);   
                                                                     else if(var_type[$3]==2)
                                                                        printf("\n\t\t\t\tValue of %c is: %c\n",$3+97,char_val[$3]);                                                                        
                                                                    }
                                                                else
                                                                {
                                                                
                                                                    printf("\n\t\t\t\tCompilation error-> %c was not declared\n",$3+97);
                                                                }

                                                            }
            
                                                        
              |VARIABLE ASSIGN expression SEMICOLON         {                                                           
                                                                if(check[$1] == 1)
                                                                {
                                                                    if(var_type[$1]==0)
                                                                        {
                                                                          int_val[$1]=$3;
                                                                          printf("\n\t\t\t\t%c is assigned by %d successfully\n",$1+97,$3); 
                                                                        }
                                                                     else if(var_type[$1]==1)
                                                                       {
                                                                         float_val[$1]=$3;
                                                                         printf("\n\t\t\t\t%c is assigned by %f successfully\n",$1+97,(float)($3));
                                                                       }
                                                                      else if(var_type[$1]==2)
                                                                       {
                                                                         float_val[$1]=$3;
                                                                         printf("\n\t\t\t\t%c is assigned by %c successfully\n",$1+97,$3);
                                                                       }
                                                                }
                                                                else
                                                                {
                                                                  printf("\n\t\tCompilation error-> %c was not declared\n",$1+97);
                                                                }
                                                        }
             
              ;


    expression: number{ $$ = $1;  
                       //printf("%f\n",$1);
                      }
             

    number:INT_VAL {$$=$1;}
          |FLOAT_VAL {$$=$1;
                      //printf("%f\n",$1);
                     }
          |CHAR_VAL  {$$=$1;}
        
          ;
              
    %%


    int yywrap(){
    return 1;
    }
    int yyerror(char *s)
    {
    fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",s);
    }
    int main()
    {
    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    yyparse();
    }
```

If I assign m_float a:=12.45.Then the output should be 12.45.But the program give me 12.000000.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared

```
%type<intVal>expression … number
```

so when you create a `number` from a `FLOAT_VAL`,  you convert it to an integer. But all of your variables are floating point, so you later store this integer as a float. The effect is really no different from the following:

```c
float value = 12.45;
int number = value;
int expr = number;
float a = expr:
printf("a = %f\n", a);
```

I hope it's obvious why
that C fragment will print out `a = 12.000000`.

Creating a calculator with multiple datatypes is not so easy. You cannot use a simple C primitive type to hold something which might be one of various different types. You would need some kind of *discriminated union*, which is a lot more work

A common solution (used by JavaScript, for example) is to use `double` as the only numeric type. (In general, you should use `double` instead of `float` anyway; `float` is not accurate enough for many computations.) A `double` can precisely represent any 32-bit integer value, so you are not losing any precision by using `double` to hold integers.

That doesn't help you with string-typed expressions, though. If you want multiple data types, you will definitely need a discriminated union type.

On typical platforms, `double` has 53 bits of precision, so you can use integers somewhat larger than could fit in an `int` but not so large as could fit in a `long long`. Occasionally, you really need 64-bit integers. If so, again the only solution is a discriminated union type.